# Android - Select all items using SelectionTracker

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I'm using [SelectionTracker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/SelectionTracker) form the `support-library-v28`
It works great, just as expected.

Only thing I need, is to enable `Select All` feature (using the `ToolBar`)

Looking at the API, I see that there is one way to select all, but that one requires creating `Iterable<Long>` with all the values, meaning, create an array which hold `Long` values from 1 to `datasource.size()`

Is there any simpler way to select all the items in my datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as I've recently had to set up the same sort of functionality, I thought I'd share my approach. Using the `setItemsSelected(Iterable<K> keys, boolean selected)` method really isn't as complex as it seems.

Yes, you will need to pass in an iterable. What I did was, loop through my data and store the index of each item as a 'long' inside of an arrayList().

EX:

```
yourData.forEachWithIndex { i, item ->
            //Be sure to start at one, just plus one 
            someOtherTempArray.add(i.toLong() + 1)
        }
```

Then I created a method that makes it easy to 'trigger' the select all functionality:

EX:

```
private fun startHandler(isChecked: Boolean){
      val handler = android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
      val runnable = Runnable {
        kotlin.run {
          mTracker!!.setItemsSelected(someOtherTempArray.asIterable(), 
                isChecked)
        }
      }
     handler.post(runnable)
  }
```

The 'isChecked' parameter, which will essentially determine if we want to select all or deselect all.

Note that I am simply using my arrayList of 'keys' (for me this is just the index of the item. However, this may differ depending on how you have your ItemDetails Builder set up) and calling the Kotlin .asIterable() function to turn it into an iterable.

I have also placed the call to setItemsSelected() inside of a handler to force the selection to take place on the UI thread.

Now whenever you want to select/deselect all, you can call the startHandler(true)!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already said in my question that I am looking for a different way than passing Iterable, BTW, why using +1 (yous said Be sure to start at one, just plus one)

Comment: I'm + 1 because my index starts at 0